# VBA Return message if cell(s) in range are blank

Tags: vba, excel, range

i am trying to return a message if any cells in a given range are blank. If i declare the range i.e.

```
Set OrderRng = [C1: C41]
```

it works fine, but if i declare it as such;

```
Set OrderRng = Range("c1:" & ActiveSheet.Range("c65536"). End(xlUp).Address).Select`
```

It does not work.

I know the second argument range is declared correctly as it always highlights the correct cells.

My entire code looks like this;

```
> Sub BlankCell() Dim OrderRng As Range On Error Resume Next
> 
>     Set OrderRng = Range("c1:" & ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").End(xlUp).Address).Select
> 
> ' Set OrderRng = [C1: C41]  ' Rm'd for testing
> 
>   Set OrderRng = OrderRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
> 
> If Err = 0 Then MsgBox "An Order ID is missing on one of your entries,
> please amend then try again" End If End Sub
```

What am i doing wrong, i know it will be obvious, but not to me.

Many thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to share the error you are getting. In this case, probably "Type Mismatch"

Comment: Please do not use `Activeheet` or `Usedrange` or even hardcode the cells to find the last row. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) Also avoid using `.Select`. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix, just remove the `.select` from the end of your range variable set line:

```
Set OrderRng = Range("c1:" & ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").End(xlUp).Address)
```

The `.select` method returns a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, so you end up with a type mismatch trying to `Set OrderRng` to `TRUE`, which is a boolean, not a range.

Also there's 100% no reason to `select` here and your code should continue on fine.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick responses, i did not appreciate not using .select by doing do so i could see the range selected.